# Bind color for IndependentValue

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am using the WPF charting toolkit: System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting

I have something like this:

```
<charting:Chart>
    <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" />
        <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" />
    </charting:Chart.Axes>

    <charting:ColumnSeries
        IndependentValuePath="RangeText"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding PercentValue}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ResultCollection}"/>
</charting:Chart>
```

Which binds to this:

```
ObservableCollection<Result> Results { get; set; }

public Result
{
    public string RangeText { get; set; }
    public float PercentValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsAligned { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is change the color of the IndependentValue text to red when IsAligned is set to true. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a Value Converter

Comment: I have not ever worked with that charting library, but sure it have an ItemTemplate, or Item Container Style, try to find it. It it just a tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do lots of formatting in the Style

```
<Style x:Key="PercentValue" TargetType="{x:Type charting:AxisLabel}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type charting:AxisLabel}">
                <TextBlock Foreground= "Red"  FontSize="8" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<charting:Chart>
    <charting:Chart.Axes>
       <charting:LinearAxis AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource PercentValue}" Orientation="Y" />
        <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" />
    </charting:Chart.Axes>

    <charting:ColumnSeries
        IndependentValuePath="RangeText"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding PercentValue}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ResultCollection}"/>
</charting:Chart>
```